# Why is my camelcase function not working on large strings?

Tags: c++

The problem states that given a string for example "oneTwoThree" return the number of words in it. Each word must start with a uppercase character except the first one which always start with lowercase.
Here is the snippet of the camelcase problem that I wrote:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<cctype>

using namespace std;


int camelcase(string s) {
    int count=0;
for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++)
{
    if(isupper(s[i])==true)
    count++;
}
count++;
return count;
}

int main()
{
    string name;
    cin>>name;
    int camel=camelcase(name);
    cout<<camel<<endl;
}
```

It runs fine for small strings but for big string test cases more than 10^5 characters say it returns nothing.

Comment: Step through with a debugger and see if the program crashes before it can output. If it does, the debugger should stop at the crash and let you examine the crash site. If it doesn't crash run it again and start stepping and watching for the unexpected. By the way, I think you have an extra `count++` in there. You just explained the extra `count++`, so ignore that part.

Comment: I have some doubts that `cin`, `cout` can properly handle strings that long. Consoles are typically limited to something around 65k characters - so printing something much larger is some sort of an error. Also, you need to verify that `int` and `size_t` are at least 4 bytes on your system.

Comment: Code can be simplified to `return 1 + std::count_if(s.begin(), s.end(), [](char c){ return isupper(c); });`.

Comment: Yup, @ALX23z (+1). OP, if you can get the exact length that it flakes out on, I will wager that it is a power of two. You have hit the string length limit

Comment: Nice suggestion, @Jarod42 OP, since you are new hear, you might not be aware of our [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) site. When your code it working, it can be interesting to post it there & see how others suggest improving it - maybe not this one, as it is quite short, but for future reference

Comment: @MawgsaysreinstateMonica As far as I know, codereview rejects code which does not work as expected, aka "broken code".

Comment: Agreed. That's why I said "When your code it working" :-)  I feel that not enough people know of that great site. I often recommend it to those who say that they are new to coding - although, as a professional of \*cough\* decades, I have also used it myself. You can always learn something from extra eyes

Comment: I recommend passing the parameter by (const) reference instead of by value; especially for large strings you'll want to avoid creating a copy, if you can avoid it. Furthermore you probably don't handle the case of an empty string correctly: I'd expect return value 0, not 1

Comment: I copied the code exactly, and it always returns 1, even for an input with 500,000 characters.  That's because of the broken `==true` test.  Once that's fixed, it works fine, even with a million characters input: `yes One | tr -d "\n" | head -c 1000000 | ./67955465`, so the problem is likely with your environment.  BTW, once you have it working, there's a lot of problems that a good [codereview.se] could help you improve.